# Why is the language of my LocaleResolver bean ignored for validation violation messages?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc, internationalization

I'd like to control the language for validation constraint violation messages with a `LocaleResolver` bean.

Given

```
import java.util.Locale;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.FixedLocaleResolver;

@Configuration
public class SpringBootFixedI18nConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        return new FixedLocaleResolver(Locale.ENGLISH);
    }
}
```

and

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class SomeRequest {
    @NotNull
    private String someValue;

    public SomeRequest() {
    }

    public SomeRequest(@NotNull String someValue) {
        this.someValue = someValue;
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.util.Set;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class SomeController {
    private static final ValidatorFactory VALIDATOR_FACTORY = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    private static final Validator VALIDATOR = VALIDATOR_FACTORY.getValidator();

    @GetMapping("/path")
    public String someMethod(@RequestBody SomeRequest someRequest) {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<SomeRequest>> violations = VALIDATOR.validate(someRequest);
        if(!violations.isEmpty()) {
            return violations.iterator().next().getMessage();
        }
        return "valid request";
    }
}
```

A simple test

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class SomeControllerIT {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void someMethod() throws Exception {
        MvcResult mockMvcResult = mockMvc.perform(get("/path")
                .content("{\"someValue\":null}")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andReturn();

        assertEquals(200, mockMvcResult.getResponse().getStatus());
        assertEquals("must not be null", mockMvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString());
    }
}
```

fails because the message is in German which is the language configured for my Ubuntu 19.10.

I'm aware that there're other mechanisms, like setting system properties (see [Hibernate Validator: Violation Message Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43725532/hibernate-validator-violation-message-language) for example), but that's not an option for me.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.0.RELEASE with

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure, but by of initializing the `Validator` manually by using

```java
... VALIDATOR_FACTORY = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
... VALIDATOR = VALIDATOR_FACTORY.getValidator();
```

The `LocaleResolver` bean might not be present on the initiated validator. Have you tried using the `Validator` provided by the `ApplicationContext`? For instance:

```java
@Autowired
private Validator validator;

@GetMapping("/path")
public String someMethod(@RequestBody SomeRequest someRequest) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<SomeRequest>> violations = validator.validate(someRequest);
...
```

By the way, are you performing the validations manually (without using [`@Valid`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation#implementing-a-rest-controller)) in order to be able to process the validation result in the method? If that is your intention, annotating the `SomeRequest` parameter with `@Valid` and by suffixing the method parameters with a `BindingResult`, the validation result will be passed as an argument instead of skipping the method:

```java
@GetMapping("/path")
public String someMethod(@Valid @RequestBody SomeRequest someRequest, BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `LocaleResolver` is not used when determining the language to use for validation error messages but the `Locale` from the `LocaleContextHolder` is.

See `org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocaleContextMessageInterpolator#interpolate(java.lang.String, javax.validation.MessageInterpolator.Context)`.

Therefore I solved this be configuring the default locale of the context on startup:

```
@Configuration
public class LocaleConfig {

    @PostConstruct
    public void configureDefaultLocale() {

        // Always use english locale no matter what the locale of the OS is,
        // e.g. when printing error messages for validation
        // Note that this apparently can't be configured with a LocaleResolver but has to be explicitly
        // set as default locale here (or on JVM level)
        LocaleContextHolder.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    }
}
```

I believe that this would still allow the use of other locales if explicitly provided in a request but didn't test this.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Messages are still translated to German.